# how to pass a list between views in django

Tags: python, django

I have a list in one view that I would like to pass to another view to be parsed.
This is what I currently have. 
The views:

```
def view1(request):
    if request.method=='POST':
        list = request.POST.values()
        HttpResponseRedirect('/urls/'+ str(list)) 

def view2(request, *list):
    #do something with list
```

the urls:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^urls/$', views.view1),
    url(r'^urls/(?P<list>[-/\w]+)$', views.view2),
)
```

so the questions are:

1. how do I form the url regex to recognize the list
2. how do I concatenate the list with the rest of the url in the HttpResponseRedirect so that it will read
3. how do i pass the list in the second view (I vaguely remember using * last time I did this but I couldn't find any useful reference material)

EDIT:
At the broader level I have a template and view which provide a list of objects in a form.  Each object is selected by a checkbox. I have a second view and template that displays data for the selected objects from the first view.  I would like the number of objects selected to not be finite or limited but that may not be an option.

Comment: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem

Comment: That's all well in good. But, if passing a list to a view isn't possible, then is my only alternative defining and passing each data item individually eg `view2(request, item1, item2, item3,...)`? And if this is the case any hints on how the regex should be formed to parse multiple ints? I would think something like `(?P<list>[-/\w]+) ,(?P<list>[-/\w]+) , (?P<list>[-/\w]+)`

Comment: You did not read the article.

Comment: Can you not just post to the second view instead of doing a redirect?

Comment: I did, maybe I misunderstood your point though. I am quite confident that what I am ultimately looking for is the ability to pass a list of request objects from one view to another.  But I'll expand if it helps.

Comment: Why a view would need such a list of objects? does any body else other than `view1` uses `view2` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Brandon suggested, posting to the second view was a usable solution.
Something along the lines of:

```
def view2(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        page_list=request.POST.values()
    else:
        HttpResponseRedirect('/urls/')
```

and then no need for regex in the urls

Answer (score 0):

> I would like the number of objects selected to not be finite or limited but that may not be an option.

It definitely is an option. Capture everything post the certain word as a single reg-ex and parse it to different "tags" within your view.