# Passing Django forms' result to a page

Tags: html, django

I have worked on this for sometime now and I have decided to seek for your help. I have an ongoing project and I am using the django framework to build the site. 
I have an html page that requests for user input, I have been able to extract the given data using the `form.cleaned_data['']`. A

```
#This is my views.py;



 from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
    from django.template import RequestContext

    from forms import CarloanForm


    def index(request):
        form = CarloanForm()
        if request.POST:
            form = CarloanForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                form.save()
        else:
            form = CarloanForm()
        return render_to_response('carloan/index.html', {'form': form},
                      context_instance=RequestContext(request))

#I am extracting the user inputs using;

amount_of_vehicle = form.cleaned_data['cost_of_vehicle_Naira'] 
tenure = form.cleaned_data['loan_repayment_tenure_Months']
interest_rate = form.cleaned_data['interest_rate_Percentage']
equity = form.cleaned_data['equity_contrib_rate_Percentage']
depreciation_rate = form.cleaned_data['depreciation_rate_Percentage']
```

What I need to do and don't know how to go about it are;

1. Carry out some operations on the data (extracted using `form.cleaned_data['']`) and I have written some lines of code to that effect;

   ```
   class LoanCalc:
       def __init__(self,amount_of_vehicle,tenure,interest_rate,equity,depreciation_rate):
           self.amount_of_vehicle = float(amount_of_vehicle)
           self.tenure = float(tenure)
           self.interest_rate = float(interest_rate)
           self.equity = float(equity)
           self.depreciation_rate = float(depreciation_rate)
       def interest(self):
           return (self.interest_rate/100) * self.amount_of_vehicle *(self.tenure/12)
       def management_fee(self):
           return 0.01 * (self.amount_of_vehicle + user.interest())
       def processing_fee(self):
           return 0.0025 *(self.amount_of_vehicle + user.interest())
       def legal_fee(self):
           return 0.0075 * (self.amount_of_vehicle + user.interest())
       def residual_amount(self):
           return 0.01 * (self.amount_of_vehicle - ((self.depreciation_rate/100) * self.amount_of_vehicle *(self.tenure/12)))
       def equity_contribution(self):
           return (self.equity/100) * self.amount_of_vehicle
       def LoanPaymentPlan(self):
           months = 1
           total_amount = self.amount_of_vehicle+user.interest()+user.management_fee()+user.processing_fee()+user.legal_fee()+user.residual_amount()
           upfront_payment = user.management_fee()+user.processing_fee()+user.legal_fee()+user.equity_contribution()+user.residual_amount()
           opening_balance = total_amount - upfront_payment
           balance = opening_balance
           while months <= self.tenure:
               if balance > 0:
                   monthly_instalment =(opening_balance/self.tenure)
                   monthly_interest = (((self.interest_rate/100) * balance)/ 12)
                   loan_payment = monthly_instalment - monthly_interest
                   closing_balance = balance - monthly_instalment
                   print'  ',months,'  ',round(balance,2),'   ', round(monthly_instalment,2),'        ',round(monthly_interest,2) \
                   , '       ',' ',round(loan_payment,2),'     ',round(closing_balance,2)
                   balance = closing_balance
                   months += 1
   return 'Thank you for using the Loan Calculator App'
   ```

and i want to carry out the operations in the code above on the extracted data.

1. I am thinking of doing it in such a way like this;

Create an empty dictionary;

```
    user = {}
    user = LoanCalc(amount_of_vehicle,tenure,interest_rate,equity,depreciation_rate)
    result= user.interest()
    result1 = user.management_fee()
     .           .
     .           .
     .           .
    result10 = user.LoanPaymentPlan()
```

1. Pass the result(s) obtained from (question 2) to the same template that generated the form.

Please help me out guys, i am still very new to django. Thanks

## This is the full stack of the referenced error am getting:

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:9000/result/

Django Version: 1.4.1
Python Version: 2.5.4
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'carloan')
Installed Middleware:
('django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "C:\Python25\Lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
  111.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "C:\Users\AJIBIKE\Documents\Circuit Atlantic\calculator\carloan\views.py" in result_page
  226.         'carloan': instance,

def result_page(request):
    if request.POST:
        form = Carloan_formForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            instance = form.save(commit=False)
            instance.interest = (instance.interest_rate/100) * instance.amount_of_vehicle * (instance.tenure/12)
            instance.save()
    else:
        form = Carloan_formForm()
    return render_to_response('carloan/result.html', {'carloan': instance,'form': form},
                  context_instance=RequestContext(request))


Exception Type: UnboundLocalError at /result/
Exception Value: local variable 'instance' referenced before assignment
```

## Latest

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.template import RequestContext
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect, HttpResponse

from forms import Carloan_formForm


def index(request):
    if request.POST:
        form = Carloan_formForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            instance = form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect ('/result/')
    form = Carloan_formForm()
    kwvars = {
            'form': form,
            }
    return render_to_response('carloan/index.html', kwvars,
                  context_instance=RequestContext(request))


def result_page(request):
    instance = None
    if request.POST:
        form = Carloan_formForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            instance = form.save(commit=False)
            instance.interest = (instance.interest_rate_Percentage/100) * instance.cost_of_vehicle_Naira * (instance.loan_repayment_tenure_Months/12)
            instance.management_fee = 0.01 * (instance.cost_of_vehicle_Naira + instance.interest)
            instance.processing_fee = 0.0025 * (instance.cost_of_vehicle_Naira + instance.interest)
            instance.legal_fee = 0.0075 * (instance.cost_of_vehicle_Naira + instance.interest)
           #i get syntax error starting from this line, and when i comment it out and the lines below, there is no syntax error.
            instance.residual_amount = 0.01 * ((instance.cost_of_vehicle_Naira - ((instance.depreciation_rate_Percentage/100) * instance.cost_of_vehicle_Naira * (instance.tenure/12))) 
            instance.equity_contribution = (instance.equity_contrib_rate_Percentage/100) * instance.cost_of_vehicle_Naira)
            instance.save()
    else:
        form = Carloan_formForm()
    return render_to_response('carloan/result.html', {'instance': instance, 'form': form},
                  context_instance=RequestContext(request))
forms.py

from django import forms
from django.forms import ModelForm

from models import Carloan_form

class Carloan_formForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Carloan_form
        exclude = ('interest', 'management_fee', 'processing_fee', 'legal_fee', \
                   'residual_amount', 'equity_contribution')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1 Save the result of the operations carried out on the extracted data in the Django Administration. (N.B: I already know how to save the user input)

Create a model to save the user's entries. `app/models.py`

```
class Carloan(models.Model) :
    # In addition to your model fields add the functions that are part of your LoanCalc
    ...
```

Then create a ModelForm: `app/forms.py`

```
class CarLoanForm(forms.ModelForm) :
    class Meta:
        model = Carloan
```

Use CarLoanForm the same way you normally would except: `app/views.py`

```
if request.POST:
    form = CarloanForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():    
        carloan = form.save()
        #pass carloan (the instance) to the template and 
        #call its functions(from LoanCalc) instead of 
        #passing all of the values separately
```

Lastly, register this Model so it appears in the admin section `app/admin.py`

```
from django.contrib import admin
from app.models import Carloan

admin.sites.register(Carloan)
```

> 2 I have divided the page into two(one for the form and the other for
>   the result) and i want to pass the result to one-half of the page to
>   enable the user to see it.

Using the steps above, carloan will be passed to the view. go ahead and render its values.

## Additionally:

### Refactor index

your index definition should be refactored slightly, or your POST bound form will never make it to the template:

```
def index(request):
    if request.POST:
        form = CarloanForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            instance = form.save()
    else :
        form = CarloanForm()

    return render_to_response('carloan/index.html', {'form': form},
              context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

### Refactor your ModelForm

**Carry out some operations on the data (extracted using form.cleaned_data['']) and I have written some lines of code to that effect;** - using a ModelForm instead of a regular django form you will get an instance of the model *with the user's values* already filled in, you reference them with *instance.field*.

**and i want to carry out the operations in the code above on the extracted data.** - the fields that you plan to calculate values for are listed in *exclude* they will not factor into form validation.

```
class CarLoanForm(forms.ModelForm) :
    class Meta:
        model = Carloan
        # exclude fields that are calculated from user input
        # NOTE: these fields must be in your model
        exclude = ('interest', 'management_fee'...)
```

### Refactor result page

**Carry out some operations on the data (extracted using form.cleaned_data['']) and I have written some lines of code to that effect;**

- in results_page under the form.is_valid check, ther is a line: `instance = form.save(commit=False)` this gets all of the values that the user submitted in a instance of the Carloan Model that has NOT been saved yet.
- further down: `instance.interest = (instance.interest_rate/100) * instance.amount_of_vehicle *(instance.tenure/12)` in this line I am calculating one of the excluded fields values (this calculation is a copy of your code).
- lastly (after all of the operations on the data have been completed) I save the instance of the model.
- then pass the instance to the template for display.

code:

```
def result_page(request):
    if request.POST:
        form = CarloanForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            # get an instance from the form but don't save it
            instance = form.save(commit=False)
            # calculate excluded field values
            instance.interest = (instance.interest_rate/100) * instance.amount_of_vehicle *(instance.tenure/12)
            ...
            # after you have calculated all of the excluded fields save the instance
            instance.save()

    else :
        form = CarloanForm()

    return render_to_response('carloan/result.html', {'carloan' : instance, 'form' : form},
                          context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

### Error:

`reference before error assignment` - What does it say was referenced before assignment? Paste the entire stack trace please.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking time out to respond to my questions. Unfortunately, you have not really addressed my questions. I already know how to save the user entries. What i want to know is how to save the result of the user entries after it much must have gone through some operations before being displayed to the user.

Comment: mainly, I wanted to illustrate using a ModelForm instead of a regular Form. I'm going to add some additional code to illustrate the calculated values.

Comment: Thank you very much Mr Francis Yaconiello for taking time out to respond to my questions. I think i am not making understandable to you enough, but i will try as much as possible to do so. Please re-check opening post, i have re-modified it. Anticipating your prompt responses.

Comment: I'm sorry if i am not understanding the question well. But based on your additional info above, I think that my solution will completely work for you. Look in my answer for bold quotes from your question, I have responded directly to them.

Comment: Thanks for stopping by to lend a helping hand. I will try to do as you have suggested but i have one question regarding "class CarLoanForm(forms.ModelForm) :
    class Meta:
        model = Carloan
        # exclude fields that are calculated from user input
        # NOTE: these fields must be in your model
        exclude = ('interest', 'management_fee'...)

Comment: I have done as you have suggested but still having referenced before assignment error and i have pasted the full stack up here. Please refer to my opening post. In addition, thanks for the refactor tutorial. I like the approach and it worked

Comment: apologies, between `def result_page(request):` and `if request.POST:` instantiate `instance = None` so that it exists regardless of whether or not the form was submitted.

Comment: Thanks so much once again. Am convinced that this approach will work but still having issues with it. In the Refactor Model, i tried adding e.g interest =(interest_rate/100) * amount_of_vehicle *(tenure/12) to the Model Field but kept having "TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'DecimalField' and 'DecimalField' ". Also tried interest = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2), although i was able to sycdb, when i tried to submit the form in the template, i recieved "IntegerError at /carloan/, carloan_carloan_form.interest may not be NULL". What should i do?

Comment: `interest` should not be in carloan_carloan_form. it should be excluded from the fields with: `exclude = ('interest', 'management_fee'...)` see: Refactor your ModelForm

Comment: Thanks for your prompt responses. Please see 'Latest' in my OP for my codes. I have done as you suggested in the Refactor Modelform and everything seems to be in order but only 'None' appears on the result page, no figures. Recall we instantiated instance = None

Comment: Thank you all for your contributions, i have been able to resolve it. Had to use the concept of OOP.

Answer (score 1):

One of the simpler ways would be to store the data in the session in one view, retrieve it in the next. The [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/sessions/) will help.[1](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/sessions/)

Having said that - there are a few other ways to approach the problem. It has been discussed more than once on SO:

- [Django Passing data between views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7763115/django-passing-data-between-views)
- [How do you pass or share variables between django views?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2570131/how-do-you-pass-or-share-variables-between-django-views)
- [how to pass a list between views in django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6416084/how-to-pass-a-list-between-views-in-django)

Comment: Thank you all for your contributions, i have been able to resolve it. Had to use the concept of OOP